# History function

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence, history

Can you tell the next element of this history function?

It is **meant and important** that `mathematics` tag isn't here!

I save you the time to [search on OEIS](https://oeis.org/?language=english), you won't find it :)

PS: I did post this puzzle yesterday but I replaced it with this one with improvements :)

- 1950 $\rightarrow$ 0
- 1951 $\rightarrow$ 1
- 1952 $\rightarrow$ 1
- 1953 $\rightarrow$ 2
- 1954 $\rightarrow$ 2
- 1955 $\rightarrow$ 0
- 1956 $\rightarrow$ 1
- 1957 $\rightarrow$ 1
- 1958 $\rightarrow$ 4
- 1959 $\rightarrow$ 2
- 1960 $\rightarrow$ 3
- 1961 $\rightarrow$ 1
- 1962 $\rightarrow$ 2
- 1963 $\rightarrow$ 3
- 1964 $\rightarrow$ 3
- 1965 $\rightarrow$ 3
- 1966 $\rightarrow$ 2
- 1967 $\rightarrow$ 4
- 1968 $\rightarrow$ 5
- 1969 $\rightarrow$ 4
- 1970 $\rightarrow$ 6
- 1971 $\rightarrow$ 4
- 1972 $\rightarrow$ 5
- 1973 $\rightarrow$ 8
- 1974 $\rightarrow$ 8
- 1975 $\rightarrow$ 7
- 1976 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1977 $\rightarrow$ 10
- 1978 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1979 $\rightarrow$ 8
- 1980 $\rightarrow$ 7
- 1981 $\rightarrow$ 8
- 1982 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1983 $\rightarrow$ 8
- 1984 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1985 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1986 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1987 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1988 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1989 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1990 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1991 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1992 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1993 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1994 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1995 $\rightarrow$ 10
- 1996 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1997 $\rightarrow$ 10
- 1998 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 1999 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 2000 $\rightarrow$ 10
- 2001 $\rightarrow$ 10
- 2002 $\rightarrow$ 10
- 2003 $\rightarrow$ 9
- 2004 $\rightarrow$ 11
- 2005 $\rightarrow$ 12
- 2006 $\rightarrow$ 11
- 2007 $\rightarrow$ 10
- 2008 $\rightarrow$ 11
- 2009 $\rightarrow$ 10
- 2010 $\rightarrow$ 12
- 2011 $\rightarrow$ 12
- 2012 $\rightarrow$ 13
- 2013 $\rightarrow$ 12
- 2014 $\rightarrow$ 12
- 2015 $\rightarrow$ 12
- 2016 $\rightarrow$ 14
- 2017 $\rightarrow$ 13
- 2018 $\rightarrow$ 14
- 2019 $\rightarrow$ 14
- 2020 $\rightarrow$ ?

Values:
0
1
1
2
2
0
1
1
4
2
3
1
2
3
3
3
2
4
5
4
6
4
5
8
8
7
9
10
9
8
7
8
9
8
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
9
10
9
10
9
9
10
10
10
9
11
12
11
10
11
10
12
12
13
12
12
12
14
13
14
14

## Hints

### 20 10 2020

Time for an hint!

> All years before 1950 are valued to -7.

Comment: Just for clarity: when you call it a "history function", are you specifically telling us that the year-like numbers _do actually represent years_?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan, yes! input numbers are years :)

Comment: With these years, and numbers in this ballpark, I've been so sure in my head that this is something to do with rot13(Sbezhyn 1) that I now can't see any other possibilities. I'm guessing it's not or I would have spotted it by now... Come on head, get empty again!

Comment: Is, for instance, binary calculation / observation (eg numbers of bits) considered as 'maths'?

Comment: @e2-e4, for `math` and `computer-science` tag, I could do the same remark :) I really like your nickname by the way ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

> 10

Which is determined by...

> The number of FIA Formula One World Championship races held in that year, minus seven. There are (so far) 17 confirmed races for 2020, and so 17 - 7 = 10

Comment: Oof. @Stiv (and many others) are gonna punch themselves after that revelation :P

Comment: GOSH, I WAS RIGHT!